# Android and colors

Tags: android, colors

I have a problem with changing colors in android.
I have a list where I add elements using:

```
colorsPictures.add(Color.BLUE);
colorsPictures.add(Color.YELLOW);
colorsPictures.add(Color.BLACK);
```

In onCreate() I implement some like this:

```
pictureOne.setImageResource(colorsPictures.get(0)));
pictureTwo.setImageResource(colorsPictures.get(1));
```

pictureOne and pictureTwo are:

```
    pictureOne = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPicture1);
    pictureTwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewPicture2);
```

I want to both of my imageview change their color on blue and yellow when I start activity. I think that I have a bug in adding to my list. I know that I can change color in layout, but I must do this, this way. Help me pls.

For example:
I have two imageViews on layout. They have white colors. I want to change their colors when I run activity and I click the button. OnClick listener is implemented but I get nullpointexception when I try change colors.

Comment: If you have a image in background of your image view,then Change color will not show any background.It will simply show background image.For more info [Read This](http://konsentia.com/2011/03/dynamically-changing-the-background-color-in-android-widgets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `setImageResource(int resId)` and the method argument is a drawable resource, not a color. If you look at your logs you will probably see a warning or exception saying that the resource is not found.

You can use this instead:

```
pictureOne.setBackgroundColor(colorsPictures.get(0)));
pictureTwo.setBackgroundColor(colorsPictures.get(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

If your only goal is to change the color of the background why dont you just do,

```
pictureone.setBackgroundResource(colorsPicture.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameter of setImageResource is resource id. You are puting color in it. Use:

```
pictureOne.setBackgroundColor(colorsPictures.get(0)));
```

Or define yoyr colors in colors.xml and use:

pictureTwo.setImageResource(R.color.YOUR_COLOR_ID);

Answer (score 0):

you have set at dynamically then you have do like..try like this..

```
setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.info_button_text_color));
```

hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

**setImageResource** is used to set any image which is available in **drawable** folder as below

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

You are using this method to set color with direct value. It will give unknown result, because at run time the color value will be considered as resource id.